# Host C# winforms in VB6 applications

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6

I have a VB 6 application and we are starting to port it over to C#.  We have finished one of the screens and wanted to see if there was an incremental way of hosting the winform within VB to start to have the existing users get used to new screens.  This is a migration strategy..

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you [looked at this?](http://hubpages.com/hub/Interop_Forms_Toolkit_10) Direct Link to [Product here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb419144.aspx)

Comment: Useful stuff.  I would have lost a lot of money betting that there was no way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

The Interop Forms Toolkit allows you to create .NET Forms and User Controls that can be used in VB 6.0 applications. This allows you to migrate VB 6.0 applications to .NET over time (a form or part of a form at a time). However, the toolkit relies on features from the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly and the VB.NET compiler so it doesn't work with C#.

There are a couple articles/samples on [CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/) that discuss the toolkit and how to use it with C#.

[Interop Forms Toolkit 2.0 Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/VB6InteropToolkit2.aspx)

[VB6 - C# Interop Form Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/VB6_-_C__Interop_Form.aspx)

Beth Massi has several articles and webcasts on the use of the Toolkit you can use for reference. Check out [her blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi) for links to resources.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any third party tools out anything outside of what comes with Visual Studio if you mainly just want your VB6 program to cause a .NET Winform to be displayed.

The approach we have taken here is to expose a C# wrapper class to VB6 by giving it a COM interface. This class has a few methods which can be called from VB6. They, in turn, instantiate and then show the Winform. It works well.