# Can I write a Winforms UI that is callable from both .net6 and vb6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, vb6, winforms-interop

Currently I can call a framework 4.7.2 library from VB6 via Com Interop.
Is it possible to write a UI that can be called from both .net6 and VB6 so as to have only one UI Code base.
That is without switching the target framework back and forth.

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71073041/how-can-i-tell-if-net-framework-winforms-code-is-callable-from-net-core6) question.

Comment: Are you really asking about the VB6 part of this? Or the NET472 vs NET6 aspect?  Or is the question, can you access call into NET6 Winforms from VB6? (Because you definitely can do that from VB6 to NET472.)

Comment: If you are just trying to open a .NET winform initiated by VB6, then you might only need https://stackoverflow.com/a/54290270/3195477

Comment: Or maybe this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098223/is-it-possible-to-use-windows-forms-controls-directly-on-a-vb6-form

Comment: @StayOnTarget I am asking about the Net472 vs Net6 aspect. I guess I should just try it.

Comment: Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/